# how to handle condtion in VBScript Loop

Tags: vbscript

I've two Input Fields and Two Submit Button on a page. 
InputField1 "Code"
InputField2 "Amount"
Button1 "Save"
Button2 "Save And Add Another"

Having trouble writing the logic. i should only hit save when i've only one item item and move on. if mutltiple then i need to hit button2 and follow the process and at the end i need to hit save. Any help will be highly apreciated. I'm just not sure how do i handle the save button.

```
sCode="100:500"
sAmount="500:500"
arrCCode=Split(sCode,":")
arrAmount=Split(sAmount,":")

For i = 0 To UBound(arrCCode)

  If i > UBound(arrCCode) Then
    Exit For
    Else 
        MsgBox arrCCod(i)
        MsgBox arrAmount(i)


  End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

I think i got it,,,

```
sCode="100:500"
sAmount="500:500"
arrCCode=Split(sCode,":")
arrAmount=Split(sAmount,":")

For i = 0 To UBound(arrCCode)

  'If i > UBound(arrCCode) Then
    'Exit For
    'Else 
        MsgBox arrCCod(i)
        MsgBox arrAmount(i)
        If i = UBound(arrCCod) Then
            msgbox "Save"
            Exit For
        Else
            Msgbox "Save and add"
        End 

  'End If
Next
```